# How to search through combobox with a string containing a wildcat?

Tags: c#, combobox, full-text-search

I have a combo-box that contains lots of entries like this small extract

```
1R09ST75057
1R11ST75070
1R15ST75086
1R23ST75090
2R05HS75063
2R05ST75063
3R05ST75086
2R07HS75086
```

The user now enters some information in the form that result in a string being produced that has a wildcat (unknown) character in it at the second character position

```
3?05ST75086
```

I now want to take this string and search\filter through the combo-box list and be left with this item as selected or a small set of strings.

If I know the string without the wildcat I can use the following to select it in the Combo-box.

```
 cmbobx_axrs75.SelectedIndex = cmbobx_axrs75.Items.IndexOf("2R05HS75063");
```

I thought I could first create a small subset that all have the first char the same then make a substring of each minus the first two chars and check this but I can have a large amount of entries and this will take too much time there must be an easier way?

Any ideas how I can do this with the wildcat in the string please?

Added info:

I want to end up with the selected item in the Combobox matching my string.

I choose from items on the form and result in string 3?05ST75086. I now want to take this and search to find which one it is and select it. So from list below

```
1R05ST75086
2R05ST75086
3R05ST75086
6R05ST75086
3R05GT75086
3R05ST75186
```

I would end up with selected item in Combo-box as

```
3R05ST75086
```

Comment: You might want to look into regular expressions (Regex-Class) for this.

Comment: Can you expand on what your end goal is? Do you want a list of the strings that start with the same first two characters or just the character you are wildcarding? For example, do you want a list of all the strings that start with `3R` or all the strings that start with `1R, 2R 3R, ...`? And which one is being selected in the combobox?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all that helped I used a combination of items from all answers so everyone helped me answer this.

I added this function from the answers as it seems a good idea, thanks

```
 private static string ConvertWildCardToRegex(string value)
    {
        return "^" + Regex.Escape(value).Replace("\\?", ".").Replace("\\*", ".*") + "$";
    }
```

Then I get the combo box items into a list. I search the list and make some more decisions based on the result of the search.

```
List<string> comboBoxValues = new List<string>();

       for (int i = 0; i < cmbobx_in_focus.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            comboBoxValues.Add(cmbobx_in_focus.GetItemText(cmbobx_in_focus.Items[i]));

        }

string[] results = comboBoxValues
                .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, ConvertWildCardToRegex(lbl_raster_used.Text)))
                .ToArray();
```

I now have array called results which is easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions. Something like this:

```
string[] data = new string[]
{
    "1R09ST75057",
    "1R11ST75070",
    "1R15ST75086",
    "1R23ST75090",
    "2R05HS75063",
    "2R05ST75063",
    "3R05ST75086",
    "2R07HS75086"
};

string pattern = "3*05ST75086";
string[] results = data
    .Where(x => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Your Regex pattern will only make the `3` character optional. The asterisks `*` is not the correct wildcard for this situation. He needs a placeholder like the dot `.` to fill the place with anything or a placeholder like `[a-zA-Z]` to only allow letters.

Comment: @dvo: The value of `pattern` is just an example based on *the user now enters some information in the form that result in a string being produced that has a wildcat (unknown) character in it at the second character position*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for this task. First, you need a method to convert your pattern string to Regex like this (it should handle "*" and "?" wildcards):

```
private static string ConvertWildCardToRegex(string value)
{
    return "^" + Regex.Escape(value).Replace("\\?", ".").Replace("\\*", ".*") + "$";
}
```

Then you will use it like the following:

```
List<string> comboBoxValues = new List<string>()
        {
            "1R09ST75057",
            "1R11ST75070",
            "1R15ST75086",
            "1R23ST75090",
            "2R05HS75063",
            "2R05ST75063",
            "3R05ST75086",
            "2R07HS75086"
        };

string searchPattern = "3?05ST75086";
string patternAsRegex = ConvertWildCardToRegex(searchPattern);
var selected = comboBoxValues.FirstOrDefault(c => Regex.IsMatch(c, patternAsRegex));
if (selected != null)
{
    int selectedIndex = comboBoxValues.IndexOf(selected);
}
```

This assumes you only care about first found match. If you need all matches then substitute FirstOrDefault(...) with Where(...) clause and swap "if" statement with a foreach loop.